# SVM model predicts instances with probability scores greater than 0.1(default threshold 0.5) as positives

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, prediction

I'm working on a binary classification problem. I had this situation that I used the logistic regression and support vector machine model imported from sklearn. These two models were fit with the same , imbalanced training data and class weights were adjusted. And they have achieved comparable performances. When I used these two pre-trained models to predict a new dataset. The LR model and the SVM models predicted similar number of instances as positives. And the predicted instances share a big overlap.

However, when I looked at the probability scores of being classified as positives, the distribution by LR is from 0.5 to 1 while the SVM starts from around 0.1. I called the function `model.predict(prediction_data)` to find out the instances predicted as each class and the function
`model.predict_proba(prediction_data)` to give the probability scores of being classified as 0(neg) and 1(pos), and assume they all have a default threshold 0.5.

There is no error in my code and I have no idea why the SVM predicted instances with probability scores < 0.5 as positives as well. Any thoughts on how to interpret this situation?

Answer (score 3):

That's a known fact in `sklearn` when it comes to binary classification problems with `SVC()`, which is reported, for instance, in these github issues
([here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13211) and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13662)). Moreover, it is also
reported in the [User guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-and-probabilities) where it is said that:

> In addition, the probability estimates may be inconsistent with the scores:
> the “argmax” of the scores may not be the argmax of the probabilities; in binary classification, a sample may be labeled by predict as belonging to the positive class even if the output of predict_proba is less than 0.5; and similarly, it could be labeled as negative even if the output of predict_proba is more than 0.5.

or directly within [libsvm faq](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/faq.html), where it is said that

> Let's just consider two-class classification here. After probability information is obtained in training, we do not have prob > = 0.5 if and only if decision value >= 0.

All in all, the point is that:

- on one side, predictions are based on `decision_function` values: if the decision value computed on a new instance is positive, the predicted class is the positive class and viceversa.
- on the other side, as stated within one of the github issues, `np.argmax(self.predict_proba(X), axis=1) != self.predict(X)` which is where the inconsistency comes from. In other terms, in order to always have consistency on binary classification problems you would need a classifier whose predictions are based on the output of `predict_proba()` (which is btw what you'll get when considering [calibrators](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html#calibrating-a-classifier)), like so:

  ```
   def predict(self, X):
       y_proba = self.predict_proba(X)
       return np.argmax(y_proba, axis=1)
  ```

I'd also suggest [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708301/libsvm-different-result-with-without-probabilities) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll check it out to use some calibration methods to calibrate these classifiers.