# understanding sklearn calibratedClassifierCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, probability, calibration

Hi all I am having trouble understanding how to use the output of `sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV`.

I have calibrated my binary classifier using this method, and results are greatly improved. However I am not sure how to interpret the results.
[sklearn guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html#calibration) states that, after calibration,

> the output of `predict_proba` method can be directly interpreted as a
> confidence level. For instance, a well calibrated (binary) classifier should classify the samples such that among the samples to which it gave a predict_proba value close to 0.8, approximately 80% actually belong to the positive class.

Now I would like to reduce false positive by applying a cutoff at .6 for the model to predict label `True`. Without the calibration, I would have simply used `my_model.predict_proba() > .6`.
However, it seems that after calibration the meaning of predict_proba has changed, so I am not sure if I can do that anymore.

From a quick testing it seems that predict and predict_proba follow the same logic I would expect before calibration. The output of:

```
pred = my_model.predict(valid_x)
proba= my_model.predict_proba(valid_x)
pd.DataFrame({"label": pred, "proba": proba[:,1]})
```

is the following:
[image]

Where everything that has a probability of above .5 gets to be classifed as True, and everything below .5 as False.

Can you confirm that, after calibration, I can still use `predict_proba` to apply a different cutoff to identify my labels?

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaYpj.png) https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html#calibration

Comment: Please fix your links; you have a link supposedly to sklearn documentation (where you quote from) which actually links to an image of your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, you can actually use `predict_proba()` after calibration to apply a different cutoff.

What happens within class `CalibratedClassifierCV` (as you noticed) is effectively that the output of `predict()` is based on the output of `predict_proba()` (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/calibration.py#L443) for reference), i.e. `np.argmax(self.predict_proba(X), axis=1) == self.predict(X)`.

On the other side, for the non-calibrated classifier that you're passing to `CalibratedClassifierCV` (depending on whether it is a probabilistic classifier or not) the above equality may or may not hold (e.g. it does not for an `SVC()` classifier - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68475534/svm-model-predicts-instances-with-probability-scores-greater-than-0-1default-th/70049005#70049005), for instance, for some other details on this).