# What's the interpretation of the `partial_dependence` function output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn 1.0.2 and the [`partial_dependence`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.partial_dependence.html?highlight=partial_dependence#sklearn.inspection.partial_dependence) function (which should correspond one to one with the [`plot_partial_dependence`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.plot_partial_dependence.html)) imported like this:

```
from sklearn.inspection import partial_dependence
```

and I call it as follows in my code (same as in the documentation example):

```
out = partial_dependence(classifier, X_train, ['feature1'])
```

here `out` is a tuple containing the predictions and the grid values. I only care about the predictions. What is not clear to me is whether the `out[0]` or predictions are the fraction of the `'feature1'` on the overall prediction OR it is the full prediction result. I also don't understand why the results are so different when switching between `response_method='predict_proba'` and `response_method='decision_function'` for example for a SVM binary classifier assuming the decision boundary is 50% I would expect these two to output similar values but the difference is huge.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Your second question might be related to what's described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68475534/svm-model-predicts-instances-with-probability-scores-greater-than-0-1default-th/70049005#70049005, namely the fact that on *binary*, *non probabilistic* classifiers like `SVC()` predictions obtained via `.decision_function()` and `.predict_proba()` do not necessarily correspond.